# Overfitting after first epoch

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using convolutional neural networks (via Keras) as my model for facial expression recognition (55 subjects). My data set is quite hard and around 450k with 7 classes. I have balanced my training set per subject and per class label.

I implemented a very simple CNN architecture (with real-time data augmentation):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode=borderMode, init=initialization,  input_shape=(48, 48, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(PReLU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(PReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_output))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

After first epoch, my training loss decreases constantly while validation loss increases. Could overfitting happen that soon? Or is there a problem with my data being confusing? Should I also balance my testing set?

Comment: If you think overfitting is your problem you can try varous things to solve overfitting, e.g. data augmentation (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), more dropout, simpler net architecture and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that the task is easy to solve and after one epoch the model has learned enough to solve it, and training for more epochs just increases overfitting.

But if you have balanced the train set and not the test set, what may be happening is that you are training for one task (expression recognition on evenly distributed data) and then you are testing on a slightly different task, because the test set is not balanced.

Comment: In addition, I shuffled my test set before testing. Either way, would balancing the test set help in increasing my testing accuracy?

Comment: Shuffling the test set will have no effect on the testing accuracy, because the performance metric you are using is not dependent on the order of the samples. As for the second question, balancing your test set will increase your testing accuracy IF the low accuracy is a problem of the train and test sets not being from a similar distribution. If it is a problem of huge overfitting it won't help much.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take note of that, sounds clear to me! :)